# CHtmlView and Print Preview and Context menu

Tags: mfc, webbrowser-control, print-preview

I have a `CHtmlView` derived class. My menu has a `Print Preview` menu item. That event handler creates a special print preview derived document, and then it gets displayed:

```cpp
void CChristianLifeMinistryHtmlView::DoPrintPreview()
{
    HWND      HWND_PP, HWND_FG ;
    TCHAR     szClassName[256] ;
    ULONGLONG t1, t2 ;
    RECT      workArea;

    ExecWB(OLECMDID_PRINTPREVIEW, OLECMDEXECOPT_PROMPTUSER, nullptr, nullptr);

    HWND_PP = nullptr ;
    t1 = ::GetTickCount64();
    t2 = ::GetTickCount64(); // Extra line required for 'while' rearrangement.
    while (HWND_PP == nullptr && t2 - t1 <= 6000) // if found or Timeout reached...
    {
        HWND_FG = ::GetForegroundWindow(); // Get the ForeGroundWindow
        if (HWND_FG != nullptr)
        {
            ::GetClassName(HWND_FG, szClassName, 256 );
            if (lstrcmp(szClassName, IE_PPREVIEWCLASS) == 0) // Check for Print Preview Dialog
                HWND_PP = HWND_FG ;
        }

        theApp.PumpMessage();
        t2 = ::GetTickCount64();
    }

    if (HWND_PP != nullptr)
    {
        // AJT V3.01 BUG Fix - showing maximized crops bottom of preview dialog
        ::SystemParametersInfo( SPI_GETWORKAREA, 0, &workArea, 0 );
        ::MoveWindow(HWND_PP, workArea.left, workArea.top,
            workArea.right - workArea.left, workArea.bottom - workArea.top, TRUE);

    }

}
```

This works fine. I have zero problems with it. The problem is if the user right-clicks the actual view and chooses print from there:

[image: Context Menu]

I don't know how to intercept this menu entry. Ideally it needs to redirect the action back to my main dialog so it can do the print preview correctly.

I don't want to disable the context menu because it has other choices there that are useful, like, view source. But I would like to add my own behaviour for the context menu print and print preview actions.

Is this possible?

Just wondered if anyone else has had success with this?

---

This question relates to:

- [Is it not possible to add our own menu items on the CHtmlView context menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60505381/is-it-not-possible-to-add-our-own-menu-items-on-the-chtmlview-context-menu)

Comment: The best answer to this is the following [article](https://ehsanakhgari.org/article/visual-c/2008-06-22/custom-webbrowser-context-menus)

Comment: @xMRi Thanks for this excellent article. I have to read it again to digest properly. However, it looks like I have a decision to make, unless I am missing something. There are three scenarios: Scenario 1:  Adding a new menu item to all applications using the WebBrowser control; Scenario 2:  Showing a whole customized WebBrowser context menu inside your application; Scenario 3:  Customizing the standard WebBrowser context menu. It looks like I need scenario 3. I think.

Comment: @xMRi I tried compiling the third scenario in Visual Studio 2017 but I hot some build errors in both Debug and Release modes. I notice the source code in the ZIP is dated 2002 and refers to MFC 6 and MFC 7 in the article. Am I right in saying we are now on MFC 10? Does it match the SDK? Anyway, I can't get the samples to compile in themselves.

Comment: I just tried to get the szenario 3 to run. I just turned /Gy compiler settings to use the inherited settings. The problem was just to set some interface definitions form protected to public.Change just each `protected:` clause before `BEGIN_INTERFACE_PART` into `public:`. The VC6 compiler was bad about C++ standards.

Comment: @xMRi I followed your instructions. Thanks. It compiles. I have one warning `_WIN32_WINNT not defined. Defaulting to _WIN32_WINNT_MAXVER (see WinSDKVer.h)`. But using scenario 3 I find that right-click does nothing now. I even get a script error several times.

Comment: Unfortunately the original link referred to in the comments also 404s now too.

Comment: archive.org:
https://web.archive.org/web/20180125183350/https://ehsanakhgari.org/article/visual-c/2008-06-22/custom-webbrowser-context-menus

Comment: I have created a spin off question to this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60505381/is-it-not-possible-to-add-our-own-menu-items-on-the-chtmlview-context-menu At the moment I have replaced the context menu and removed the Print Preview features because I can't supersede their behaviour.