# Why am I limited to only 2 custom menu items on IE context menu?

Tags: internet-explorer, contextmenu

I am trying to add an item to my web browser context menu:

```
IDR_MENU_HTML_POPUP MENU
BEGIN
    POPUP "CustomPopup"
    BEGIN
        MENUITEM "Select All\tCTRL + A",        31
        MENUITEM SEPARATOR
        MENUITEM "Export",                      CUSTOM_MENU_EXPORT
        MENUITEM SEPARATOR
        MENUITEM "Find\tCTRL + F",              67
        MENUITEM SEPARATOR
        MENUITEM "Page Setup",                  2004
        MENUITEM "Print Preview",               2003
        MENUITEM SEPARATOR
        MENUITEM "Refresh\tF5",                 2300
        MENUITEM SEPARATOR
        MENUITEM "View Source",                 2139
        MENUITEM "View XML",                    CUSTOM_MENU_VIEW_XML
        MENUITEM "Open File Location",          CUSTOM_MENU_OPEN_FILE_LOCATION
    END
END
```

I already have an answer that I put together here ([Is it not possible to add our own menu items on the CHtmlView context menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60505381/is-it-not-possible-to-add-our-own-menu-items-on-the-chtmlview-context-menu)) so in theory I expected it to work.

`CUSTOM_MENU_OPEN_FILE_LOCATION` is defined as `3702` so it iw within this rule:

> The menu IDs for all custom menu items fall between `IDM_MENUEXT_FIRST__` and `IDM_MENUEXT_LAST__` for a maximum of 33 custom commands.

For some reson this menu item is disabled when I display the context menu.

Comment: It seems like I can only use `3700` and `3701`.

Comment: I ended up removing the Export menu item and renumbering the new item as 3701. Now it works. Why am I limited to only 2 menu items?

Comment: Adding a custom context menu is actually adding the corresponding value in the registry. But I don't know much about C++ development, I'm afraid I can't determine the cause of your problem. Here's a nice [related article](https://www.codeguru.com/soap/customize-an-ie-context-menu-to-add-codeguru-favorites/) that you can simply refer to.

Comment: @XudongPeng Thanks for the link. If I am right, using the registry affects *all instances* of the browser on the PC. This is why I do it this way instead as it only affects my `CHtmlView` browser. This way is much simpler too to code too. BTW. It is interesting that the sample you linked to also only adds **two** items. 